# How do I set up Rails for French language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I have to develop a Ruby on Rails app for my company and don't know how to configure it for a French site.

I don't need multiple language support, I just want to have error messages, pluralization and date format for French.

I tried to set:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

in my `application.rb` file but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Are these features already implemented in RoR 3? Or I will have to translate these things myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Rails comes with en locale only. You can get additional locales here:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale/

Comment: Hi, that's what i was searching for. Do you know if there exist something for the inflection module (for the pluralization)?

Answer (score 5):

To set your application to French you need to set `config.i18n.default_locale = :fr` in your `config/application.rb`, create `fr.yml` file in your aplication `config/locales` folder and add needed localized strings to this file. Check this out: 
[fr.yml](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/e5902fa2cdd556479e507310e969af8483abe332/rails/locale/fr.yml)

this will help you to translate dates and etc.

Comment: This is correct. Actually `config.i18n.default_locale` is already in `config/application.rb` but commented.

Answer (score 0):

Add to [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails) your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rails-i18n'
```